# Need to DNAT mac based on vlan and destination IP match.

Tags: linux, iptables, vlan

ebtable rule is not allowing me to specify vlanid and ipv4 protocol in one rule. Also I tried this but the second rule is not getting matched for vlan packet.

```
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING --vlan-id 100 -j mark --set-mark 100 --mark-target CONTINUE
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <iface> --mark 100 --ip-dst <ip> -j dnat --to-dst <mac> --dnat-target ACCEPT
```

The second rule is not getting matched if packet comes with vlan header. Is there any way I can do DNAT mac based on matching destination ipaddress and vlan id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of current bridge filtering with ebtables: ebtables matches are specific rather than generic, and unless one adds a vlan-plus-ip match, it's not possible to match a VLAN tagged IP with *ebtables*.

Here are two methods to work around this limitation, while the first method would allow many things for other cases, the specific OP's issue cannot be dealt with it.

### [bridge-netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) (cannot work for this case)

What is instead possible for many cases (but actually not this case, see later) related to *ebtables*' poor handling of stacked protocols , is to tell the bridge code to do an *upcall* to *iptables* by [using the br_netfilter module](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html). Yes that's right, *iptables* will be run at the bridge level rather than the route/IP level. Note that currently this is a systemwide change with possible systemwide effects, including on other bridges and other namespaces ([this should become per-namespace](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/list/?series=112183&state=*) "soon", probably after kernel 5.3). Some unexpected effects and how to prevent them are described in [7. Two possible ways for frames/packets to pass through the iptables PREROUTING, FORWARD and POSTROUTING chains](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7).

```
modprobe br_netfilter
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1 #actually default
```

Note that there's [no action needed on the VLAN part](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/misc/brnf-faq.html):

> Do {ip,ip6,arp}tables see VLAN tagged IPv4/IPv6/ARP traffic on an
>   untagged bridge?
>       Yes. Kernel versions 2.6.0-test7 and above have this functionality. For disabling this, see the above question.

Now that [ebtables/iptables interactions](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html) are possible, let's look at [5. Chain traversal for bridged IP packets](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section5). It tells the frame/packet will at least do:

```
-> ebtables nat/PREROUTING -> iptables nat/PREROUTING, then
-> ebtables filter/FORWARD -> iptables filter/FORWARD ....
```

There are other cases, but one case that would be needed doesn't exist: come back to the same calling part, like:

```
-> ebtables nat/PREROUTING -> iptables some/THING -> ebtables nat/PREROUTING
```

So while depending on OP's specific layout (including the role of the interface in 2nd rule and the meaning of the MAC address, is it local? not local? etc.) there could be some options left (really needing to mark the packet to send a message from *ebtables* to *iptables*), I don't see a way.

That's why an ebtables/iptables replacement was devised that would avoid all this mess in the first place: *nftables*.

### [nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page)

The replacement *nftables* was designed with a generic usage in mind, so it wouldn't have to rely on a slightly different kernel module to do the same when handling an IP in bridge path or in route path.

nftables is a moving target, it's probably best to use nftables >= 0.8.3 and kernel >= 4.10 to get most features. This was tested with nftables 0.9.0 and kernel 5.1.x. Old nftables/kernels (eg RHEL7/CentOS7's) might not have all the required features, this has to be tested again then.

There are still some limitations for this specific case, but they appear to be on the userland *nftables* side rather than the kernel side, so I provide two ways to overcome it.

Let's add the plumbing (eg after a `nft flush ruleset`):

```
nft add table bridge nat
nft add chain bridge nat prerouting '{ type filter hook prerouting priority -300; policy accept; }'
```

If the matching IP is 192.0.2.1 and the target MAC is `02:00:00:00:00:01`, normally this one line would be enough to do the work (depending on nftables' version it has to be more or less verbosely described,I chose to be verbose, anyway it's creating the exact same bytecode and displayed back in a simplified version), but it fails:

```
# nft add rule bridge nat prerouting ether type vlan vlan id 100 vlan type ip ip daddr 192.0.2.1 ether daddr set 02:00:00:00:00:01
Error: conflicting protocols specified: vlan vs. ether
add rule bridge nat prerouting ether type vlan vlan id 100 vlan type ip ip daddr 192.0.2.1 ether daddr set 02:00:00:00:00:01
                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The *nftables* userland tool doesn't want to come back in its parsing to a lower level protocol after having followed *ether -> vlan -> ip*.

This can be solved either by splitting the rule with a user chain and put the change there:

```
nft add chain bridge nat mydnat
nft add rule bridge nat prerouting ether type vlan vlan id 100 vlan type ip ip daddr 192.0.2.1 jump mydnat
nft add rule bridge nat mydnat ether daddr set 02:00:00:00:00:01
```

or by telling *nftables* "do this, don't try to understand" with a raw payload telling to change the first 48 bits of the link layer (that is the [ethernet destination MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure)). So instead of the 3 lines above, this line will do the same:

```
nft add rule bridge nat prerouting ether type vlan vlan id 100 vlan type ip ip daddr 192.0.2.1 @ll,0,48 set 0x020000000001
```

Note that the latter method is actually using the same bytecode, doing this instead of the 3rd line of the latter method:

```
nft add rule bridge nat mydnat @ll,0,48 set 0x020000000001
```

would be decoded back to exactly the same `ether daddr set 02:00:00:00:00:01` when displaying the rule in chain *mydnat*. One can imagine a future version of *nftables* will accept it in the one liner case.

Just to tell it's working as written (ie: probably not working as intended without additional rules for ARP or context from OP etc.), here's a tcpdump on the receiving side when receiving a ping on 192.0.2.1:

```
14:03:06.542085 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype ARP, Request who-has 192.0.2.1 tell 192.0.2.2, length 28
14:03:06.542135 ae:3a:24:06:a7:da > 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype ARP, Reply 192.0.2.1 is-at ae:3a:24:06:a7:da, length 28
14:03:06.542184 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a > 02:00:00:00:00:01, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 192.0.2.2 > 192.0.2.1: ICMP echo request, id 21702, seq 1, length 64
```

with its other IP 192.0.2.11 unaffected:

```
14:11:04.026480 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype ARP, Request who-has 192.0.2.11 tell 192.0.2.2, length 28
14:11:04.026491 ae:3a:24:06:a7:da > 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype ARP, Reply 192.0.2.11 is-at ae:3a:24:06:a7:da, length 28
14:11:04.026505 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a > ae:3a:24:06:a7:da, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 192.0.2.2 > 192.0.2.11: ICMP echo request, id 21895, seq 1, length 64
14:11:04.026515 ae:3a:24:06:a7:da > 9e:72:8c:20:15:2a, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 100, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 192.0.2.11 > 192.0.2.2: ICMP echo reply, id 21895, seq 1, length 64
```

Comment: Didn't say it, but the example using nftables is on a VLAN aware bridge (vlan_filtering=1). my answer on SF: [Transparent firewall with nftables and VLANs](https://serverfault.com/questions/858556/transparent-firewall-with-nftables-and-vlans/906459#906459) has links to explanations on linux' bridge and VLAN usage.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. Appreciate it.